# Foreign key references invalid table. Could not create constraint or index

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm trying to create a table with 3 columns.  The first column should be an identity column named DescriptionsID, the second column should be a foreign key column named ProductID, and the third column should be an xml column named Description.  But, I'm receiving an error:

> Foreign Key 'FK_ProductDescriptions_bacb18ce3aa67348e55d' references invalid table 'Product' and "Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."

This is what I got:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductDescriptions (DescriptionsID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,

ProductID varchar(25) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Product(ProductID),

Description text NULL) ;
```

References Product(ProductID) has the error/red underlining

Comment: The error tells you the issue... you either don't have a table `Product` or your table product doesn't have a column `ProductID`. Given you've used the plural for `ProductDescriptions` is your product table not called `Products`?

Comment: It is almost 2019 - NO ONE should be using the text or ntext datatypes. Nor should the only real data column (Description) be nullable.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Referential Constraint, You Need to make sure that the Table and the Column which you are referring already exists in the Database.

Also, the Datatype of Both Referring Column and the Referred Column Should Be the Same

```
Column 'Product.ProductId' is not the same data type as referencing column
'ProductDescriptions.ProductID' in the foreign key
```

So Create Product Table First, and set the Product Id as Primary Key

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE ProductDescriptions 
(
    DescriptionsID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProductID INT NOT NULL 
    ,FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Product(ProductID),
    [Description] text NULL
) ;
```